# array from XML request not global

Tags: javascript, xml

I am requesting to server the names from table teacher and the response I am receiving is fine, but the Teachers array in the below code can't be accessed from other function showing Teachers.length = 0. Is this caused due to some kind of delaying handling XML request, please explain, thanks.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (document.readyState === "complete") { // PAGE HAS BEEN LOADED

  Teachers = [];
  var object = [];
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (request.status === 200) {
        object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        for(var i = 0 ; i < object.length; i++){
          Teachers.push(object[i].name.toString());
          console.log("*" + Teachers.length);
        }
      }
      console.log(Teachers.length);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/names', true);
  request.send(null);

  CreateRow();
  for(var i = 0; i < absentTeachers.length; i++){
    PrepareRow(i, "row"+(i+1));
  }
}}
```

Functions like CreateRow are using Teachers but its showing it to be empty but when I am logging the Teachers length in the request handling function its shows changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into trouble with your code because you are expecting synchronous functionality. However, Ajax requests are handled asynchronously.

Normally JS starts at the top of your code and works its way to the bottom. This is the functionality you are used to. If your request would be handled synchronously your code would work without problems. However: Javascript starts at the top, gets to the request, sends it off and progresses with the rest of your code. At that point your `Teachers` array is still empty and so nothing will happen.

What you need to do is wait until the request is completed and the data is available. (You might actually notice that the `console.log` with the empty array happens before you get the the log of the filled array).

This happens because you are calling the `console.log` once your request gets to that point. (Again, top to bottom inside the request). So to fix your problem, create a function and then call that function inside your Ajax request.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (document.readyState === "complete") { // PAGE HAS BEEN LOADED

  Teachers = [];
  var object = [];

  function createRow() {
    for(var i = 0; i < absentTeachers.length; i++){
      PrepareRow(i, "row"+(i+1));
    }
  }

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (request.status === 200) {
        object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        for(var i = 0 ; i < object.length; i++){
          Teachers.push(object[i].name.toString());
          console.log("*" + Teachers.length);
        }
      }
      createRow();
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/names', true);
  request.send(null);
}}
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Would you please up vote my answer and mark your question as answered if it helped?